# Returning JSON object to an AJAX call Efficiently

Tags: ajax, json, servlets

I have a Servlet returning a JSON object to an ajax call,but as JSON object is formed out of an excel containing 4000 rows,its taking more than two minutes for the call to return to front end..i.e,after the JSON is formed its taking about two minutes for the alert after ajax call to be displayed.Please suggest a efficient way to reduce the delay .

## This is my Servlet code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            response.setContentType("application/json");                
            String costpath = request.getParameter("fname");
            String revenuepath = request.getParameter("sname");                                              
            Path costpathobj = new Path(costpath); 
            Path revenuepathobj = new Path(revenuepath);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonObject myObj = new JsonObject();                
            Xlfunction xlfunction = new Xlfunction();
            boolean flag;
            try {
                  SheetBean[] sheetBean = new SheetBean[2];
                  flag = xlfunction.functionality(costpathobj,revenuepathobj,sheetBean);
                  JsonElement sheetobj = gson.toJsonTree(sheetBean);
                  myObj.add("projectInfo", sheetobj);
                  if(flag == true)
                  {
                  myObj.addProperty("success", true);
                  }
                  else
                      myObj.addProperty("success", false);
                  response.getWriter().write(myObj.toString());

            }
```

## This is my AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "ExcelController",
           data: "fname="+costpath+"&sname="+revenuepath,             
           dataType: "json",              
           //if received a response from the server
           success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                  
               if(data.success)
                 {
                    alert("data loaded");
                 }
```

Comment: You will need to investigate further to find the exact cause of the delay, but it sounds like JQuery is taking a while to parse the JSON and create the object tree. You can test this by changing the dataType to text and seeing if this vastly improves performance.

Comment: Thank you !! But Changing type to text did not help much.Also I see that there is no overhead in forming JSON but only in returning JSON to AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the problem seems to be slow transfer of the data from server to client, I recommend enabling GZIP compression on your Application Server. If you are using Tomcat you can add the `compression` attribute to the HTTP/1.1 Connector element in server.xml:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ... compression="on"/>
```

JSON, being plain text compresses down a lot, reducing the number of roundtrips needed to send the data.

Other things you could try:

- Reduce the amount of data you send to the client at any one time, eg by splitting it into separate calls, to be called when needed.
- If you are going to use the data to update the DOM, rather than handling the data on the client, use a jsp to output HTML and return this in your AJAX call instead, moving the hard work to the server-side.

Comment: This reduced the delay a bit..!!Thank you..But still its taking more than 1.5 minutes for the data to load in client..Please provide any other improvements that can be made..